# is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout

Tags: android, eclipse, siblings

Hello I am starting with Android developing. I am just modifying with ECLIPSE an open source example. I have only modified strings.xml and some .png files. In the Android simulator it works perfect but when I try to generate the signed apk file I receive two errors with similar description. This is one of them (the line is marking with *):

Description @+id/about_us_desc_webview is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout  cc3x_about_us.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey_background"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/cc3x_about_header_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/cc3x_headerlayout" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/about_us_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cc3x_about_header_view"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/about_title_label_top_margin"
    android:text="@string/about_us_label"
    android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
    android:textSize="@dimen/extra_large_text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/min_divider_height"
    android:layout_below="@+id/about_us_textview"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/about_title_label_side_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/about_title_label_side_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/about_page_divline" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/about_us_desc_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/about_title_label_side_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/about_title_label_side_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/min_margin_cutoff" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/about_us_desc_webview" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_screen_contact_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      * android:layout_below="@+id/about_us_desc_webview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/contact_label"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/min_divider_height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/about_screen_contact_label"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/about_title_label_side_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/about_title_label_side_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/about_page_divline" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_xcube_link"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider_bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/max_margin_size"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:text="@string/xcube_url"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_text_color"
        android:textColorLink="@color/blue_text_color"
        android:textSize="10dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_xcube_contact_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider_bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/max_margin_size"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:text="@string/xcube_contact_email"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_height" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/about_xcube_link"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/about_xcube_address"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_height" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help will be apreciated. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[android:layout_below](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_below)**

> Positions the top edge of this view below the given anchor view ID .

### When Arise

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:id="@+id/rl_rootHeader"


>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rl_Header"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_rootHeader" // Arise ,In here RelativeLayout is Parent .

    >

    //
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollRoot"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"


    >

</ScrollView>
```

### Right Way

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:id="@+id/rl_rootHeader"


>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rl_Header"


    >

    //
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollRoot"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_rootHeader"  // Call Here .This section is Child


    >

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 10):

The line

```
android:layout_below="@+id/about_us_desc_webview"
```

in your TextView is redundant. Since the RelativeLayout already has that attribute, it is useless. You can just erase that line and nothing should change.

And the reason it generates error is that, you can apply features such as below, above.. etc with an element in the same layout. Here "about_us_desc_webview" is out of the RelativeLayout and you cannot position something inside a RelativeLayout with something outside a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, The problem was with Kotlin Version. I updated the the Kotlin version and the problem "is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout" resolved

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the lines which are causing error from layout 
.xml file

Try refreshing the layout

Your layout will probably change. You can now reset it properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Properties Panel you will see layout:alignComponent has some alignment shown as "Not Found". Just clear it out. In the above example  Properties window -> textview -> layout:alignComponent  check all alignment values.